# Filter database names in SQL Management Studio 2008 R2

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to connect to my database that is located in a server with lots of other databases (that belongs to other people that are on the same hosting company).

Due to my low internet speed after I connect as I click on expanding databases most of the time I get no results waiting.

Is there a way that I can filter databases that only would load my databases ignoring the others?

Comment: It is more like configuration error - you should not see another users databases at all. Ask your hosting company, why this is done so unsecurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider denying the server permission **VIEW ANY DATABASE** to yourself or ask the server's DBA to do it.